# Onclick on Button, I need to capture the date value using React Hooks

Tags: javascript, datepicker, react-hooks

Onclick of the button.I am Capturing the values of  Firstname and Lastname. Same I need to capture the date picker vaule on Onclick of the button. I tried in below way but Unable capture the value.
        I am New to ReactJS and Can you please help in this.
        Thanks in advance.

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import "./App.css";
    import Datepicker from 'react-date-picker';

                function App() {
                  const [user, setUser] = useState({  fname: "",lname: "" });
                  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);   
                  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
                  const handleChange1 = date => {
                    setStartDate(date);
                   }

                   const handleChange = e => {
                    setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
                     };

                return (
                    <div className="App">
                      <h1>CRUD APP</h1>
                      <form>
                        <label>First Name : </label>
                        <input type="text" value={user.fname} name="fname" onChange={e => {
                            handleChange(e);
                          }}
                        />
                        <br />
                        <label>Last Name : </label>
                        <input value={user.lname} name="lname" onChange={e => {
                            handleChange(e);
                          }}
                        /> 
                        <br />
                        <label > Date : </label>
                  <Datepicker
                     selected={startDate}
                     onChange={handleChange1}
                    />
```

Onclick of the button.I am Capturing the values of  Firstname and Lastname. Same I need to capture the date picker vaule on Onclick of the button. I tried in below way but Unable capture the value.
I am New to ReactJS and Can you please help in this.
Thanks in advance.

```
 <button onClick={() => {
                let newUsers = [...users];
                newUsers.push(user);
                setUsers(newUsers);
              }}
              type="button" >
              Add User
            </button>
     </div>
          </form>
     {users.map(user => {
                return (
                  <div key={user.fname}>
                    {Object.values(user).map(val => {
                      return <p key={val}>{val}</p>;
                    })}
                                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
```

Comment: Your date picker value is your startDate. on click you are updating the users and push it a new user, after that your all state is updated:user, users and startDate

Comment: I am not getting the captured value... It would be helpful if you do the changes in the above and can you send me the updated code??
Thanks in advance

Comment: I need some more information, What do you like to do with that value?
onClick you are just update the users state which is make seance but what about the startDate value? your state is updated

Comment: when I click that button I just want to get the date, which date I selected.I dont need to update ...please help me

Comment: it's your startDate variable

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onClick={() => {
  let newUsers = [...users];
  newUsers.push(user);
  setUsers(newUsers);
  // here you capture your startDate variable

}}
  type="button" >
  Add User
</button>
</div >
</form >
{
  users.map(user => {
    return (
      <div key={user.fname}>
        {Object.values(user).map(val => {
          return <p key={val}>{val}</p>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  })
}
</div >
```